# Rewrite Polymer 1.0 snippet to Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have found a Polymer 1 sample and I would like to use it in my Polymer 2 application.

```
   <app-header-layout>

    <app-header fixed effects="waterfall" slot="header">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button id="toggle" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>Inbox</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <app-drawer-layout id="drawerLayout">

      <app-drawer slot="drawer">
         ...
      </app-drawer>

      <sample-content size="100"></sample-content>

    </app-drawer-layout>

  </app-header-layout>

  <script>
    var drawerLayout = document.getElementById('drawerLayout');
    toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (drawerLayout.forceNarrow || !drawerLayout.narrow) {
        drawerLayout.forceNarrow = !drawerLayout.forceNarrow;
      } else {
        drawerLayout.drawer.toggle();
      }
    });
  </script>
```

The small part that would have to be changed for Polymer 2 is just the js code at the bottom, but since I am new to Polymer and js, all my previous attempts to change the code to the new ES6 syntax didn't work out.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You can search each of these elements (like 'app-header-layout', 'app-toolbar', 'app-drawer') on this link: https://www.webcomponents.org/author/PolymerElements
It will display the latest version by default (Polymer 2), you can change the version from the dropdown(next to the name of the element when selected) to older and compare.

Comment: @Harman I was just including the HTML to explain the javascript snippet at the end. I would only like to 'translate' the few lines of Polymer 1.0 javascript code into the new ES6 syntax of Polymer 2.0, since the syntax changed in an incompatible way between 1 and 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The Polymer 2.0 equivalent (in ES6) of that JavaScript would be this element definition:

```
class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }

  ready() {
    super.ready();

    const drawerLayout = this.$.drawerLayout;
    this.$.toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (drawerLayout.forceNarrow || !drawerLayout.narrow) {
        drawerLayout.forceNarrow = !drawerLayout.forceNarrow;
      } else {
        drawerLayout.drawer.toggle();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gGdjNr?editors=1010)